# TryParse double values

Tags: c#, tryparse

I need validate double values. When I `TryParse .00 or ,00` return `false`, but I allow this values must true.

This code not work correctly for this case

model = ,00 or .002 or ,789 or .12 ...

```
double number;
double.TryParse(model, NumberStyles.Any, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out number)
```

Comment: Why don't you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Running this `".00"` parses to `0` successfully, and `",00"` returns false.

Comment: I need ",00" return true also

Comment: @DStanley `NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo` means culture independent doesn't it?

Comment: @asawyer yes, sorry - didn't see that part at first.

Comment: @zrabzdn what should `12.345,67` return?  How about `123,456`?

Comment: What if `"1.001"` is passed in?  What about "1,001"?  How do you know if either one really means "one-thousand-and one" or "one and one-thousandth"?

Comment: @asawyer, no it is not culture independent. It uses a built-in culture setting which is different. It uses `.` as a decimal seperator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop all supported cultures:

```
bool parsable = false;
double number = 0;
var supportedCultures = new[] { CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE") };
foreach(var culture in supportedCultures)
{
    parsable = double.TryParse(model, NumberStyles.Any, culture, out number);
    if (parsable)
        break;
}
```

or with LINQ:

```
CultureInfo thisCulture = supportedCultures
    .FirstOrDefault(c => double.TryParse(model, NumberStyles.Any, c, out number));
if (thisCulture != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number was parsable to " + number);
}
```

old approach, too error-prone as asawyer has pointed out(`"1,000,000.00"`):

<strike>You could replace commas with dots:</strike>

```
bool parsable = double.TryParse(model.Replace(",", "."), NumberStyles.Any, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out number);
```

Comment: How will `"1,000,000.00"` parse with this change?

Comment: String replacement is a dirty and potentially broken hack. Looping through the cultures you want to support is the right approach since this is, in fact, what parsing both `.00` and `,00` implies.

Comment: @asawyer: i have "deleted" this approach since it's really error-prone.

Comment: @TimSchmelter A `SortedList` might be a nice improvement, too, since the OP could specify which cultures should be tried first.

Comment: @Yuck: But he could use a normal list too since `FirstOrDefault` (or the loop) will break on the first match so the culture with the lowest index.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo` you are forcing the parser to treat `.` as the decimal separator and `,` as the thousands separator.  So

```
double.TryParse(".002", out number)
```

would return true, but

```
double.TryParse(",789", out number)
```

would not.

If you want to support multiple formats you'd have to call `TryParse` *for each format*. There's not a way to try and parse a number that would be valid in an format because they could return different value.  `"123,456"` could be interpreted two different ways depending on what culture you were using.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can really do this safely.  If you manage to get your system to handle both ways of defining `"."` and `","` as the decimal separator and grouping separator, then you run into issues of ambiguity.

For instance, what if `"1.001"` is passed in? What about `"1,001"`? How do you know if either one really means "one-thousand-and one" or "one and one-thousandth"?