# C# Validate input as double

Tags: c#

I would like to validate my input as bigger than or equal to 0 and as double. This is what i have so far:

```
string aBalBeginS;
double abalbeginVal;

Console.Write("Account Balance at the beginning: $");
aBalBeginS = Console.ReadLine();
abalbeginVal = double.Parse(aBalBeginS);
if (aBalBeginS == "" || abalbeginVal <= 0)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Invalid data entered - no value redorded");
   aBalBeginS = null;
}
```

How do i add to check if input is a number. I tried double.TryParse, but without luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TryParse double values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782318/tryparse-double-values)

Comment: double.TryParse(aBalBeginS, out doubleValue )

Comment: if(double.TryParse(aBalBeginS,out abalbeginVal)){Console.WriteLine("Invalid data entered - no value redorded");
   aBalBeginS = null;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track with `double.TryParse()`

```
double abalbeginVal;
bool parsed = double.TryParse(aBalBeginS, out abalbeginVal);
if (parsed && abalbeginVal >=0.0)
{
    // We're good
}
else
{
    // Did not pass check
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
Console.Write("Account Balance at the beginning: $");
            aBalBeginC = Console.ReadLine();

            //abalbeginVal = double.Parse(aBalBeginC);
            if (double.TryParse(aBalBeginC, out abalbeginVal) == false || aBalBeginC == "" || abalbeginVal <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid data entered - no value redorded");
                aBalBeginC = null;
            }
```

Thx.